# What to prioritize for heavy Skype usage and large drawing review

Tags: laptop, memory, cpu, gpu

I'm helping my friend find a new laptop that is capable of handling his workload. He's at a remote office, and therefore runs Skype for business 24/7. Now Skype is a massive resource hog, especially when screen-sharing, which he does often. He often has several Excel sheets, a couple Chrome windows, and several large PDF documents (arhcitectural drawing sets, engineering and fabrication drawing, etc.). He also does a bit of rough 3D modelling using Trimble Sketchup.

He currently has a 2-3 year old Dell XPS 15, with a 4K screen and an i7 with 16GB of RAM. He has a 1TB SSD. What he finds is that if he's trying to zoom in and out in a drawing set or rotate a 3D model while screen-sharing to coworkers or customers, the computer slows down to a snail's pace. Now I know Skype is primarily to blame here, but as it's part of our Office 365 subscription, it's too easy to fall back on.

Can someone guide me to what specs to prioritize for this workload?

Thanks!

Comment: Please read our FAQ – hardware shopping questions are off topic here: [help/on-topic]

Comment: Stack Exchange has a global 'no shopping questions' policy - see [Q&A is Hard, Let’s Go Shopping!](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) - with 2 exceptions - https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ & https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ BTW, CAD has considerably different GPU acceleration requirement than your standard 'gamer' lappy. Look into NVidia Quadro cards for CAD [idk if they do mobile versions, though]

Comment: @Albin Good idea. I did so. Looks a bit more technical now 

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks for the referral. It's not heavy CAD, just light modelling, no doesn't worry me too much.